# Suppress fixed effects coefficients in R

Tags: r, summary, lm

is there a way to suppress the coefficients for fixed effects in a linear model when using the summary() function (e.g. the equivalent of the absorb() function in stata). For example, I would like to have the summary function output just the intercept and x rather than the coefficients and standard errors for the factors as well:

```
frame <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),25))
summary(lm(y~x + as.factor(z), data = frame)) 

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + as.factor(z), data = frame)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.2417 -0.6407  0.1783  0.5789  2.4347 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   -0.25829    0.19196  -1.346   0.1816  
 x              0.09983    0.09788   1.020   0.3104
```

...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do any of these:

```
mod <- lm(y~x + as.factor(z), data = frame)
coef(mod)[c("(Intercept)", "x")]
# (Intercept)           x 
#  0.12357491 -0.06430765 
coef(mod)[grepl("Intercept|x", names(coef(mod)))]
# (Intercept)           x 
#  0.12357491 -0.06430765 
coef(mod)[1:2]
# (Intercept)           x 
#  0.12357491 -0.06430765 
mod$coefficients[1:2]
# (Intercept)           x 
#  0.12357491 -0.06430765
```

Comment: Is there anything that shows the whole output?  Something that is more general than just grabbing the coefficients?

Comment: @robertevansanders - I answered the question at hand.  OP wanted the intercept and x. If you have a question, you can pose it to the community.  Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I'll change it, but his question is incoherent.  First he says he wants to just suppress the fixed effects but have the summary and then he says that he wants to have only the intercept and coefficient.  I took his question to mean the first thing since that's what I was looking for. I was looking how to do the first thing and many answers to these questions did not do it, until i found the package "lfe".

Comment: Seems like that confusion might be best cleared up by commenting under the question then waiting for a response.  OP checked this answer, so it solved his immediate problem.  Not really sure what you want me to do about it.

Comment: My bad, I'll change it back. (Do a small edit so I can)  I simply downvoted answers that did not do that first part.  It was surprisingly hard to find...!

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend the `stargazer` package:

```
frame <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),25))
summary(lm(y~x + as.factor(z), data = frame)) 
model <- lm(y~x + as.factor(z), data = frame)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model, type="text")
stargazer(model, omit = "z", type="text")
```

[image]